# Want to configure OAuth for some URLs starts with "/api/v2"(has role USER) and want to configure X-API-KEY for some URLs which starts with "/api/v1"

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

The code I have written below works like if X-API-KEY is failing(for 'api/v1') it is going to OAuth. I want to throw an access denied error when it fails. I don't wish to do OAuth validation for URLs that start with "/api/v1". And also X-API-KEY validation should not be done for "api/v2/**", I need only OAuth for this.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    OAuth2LoginConfig oAuth2UserService;
    
    @Autowired
    CustomOidcUserService customOidcUserService;
    
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/v2/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(apiKeyFilter(), ApiKeyFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(this.customOidcUserService);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ApiKeyFilter apiKeyFilter() {
        ApiKeyFilter apiKeyFilter = new ApiKeyFilter();
        apiKeyFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
            if(authentication.getPrincipal()!=null) {
                String pricipal = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
                if(pricipal.equals("test1")) {
                    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                } else {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("Error");
                }
            }
            return authentication;
        });
        return apiKeyFilter;
    }
}
```

I need some help.

Thanks in advance.